# take input from html as type=date & Save date in Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, date

I have taken date from the form as

```
Date Of Birth <input type="date" name="dateOfBirth"/>
```

and redirected the input to a jsp page and took the input as

```
<jsp:useBean id="doctor" class="com.project.ocs.bean.DoctorBean"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="dateOfBirth" name="doctor"/>
```

and in the bean class i have done

```
import java.util.Date;

Date dateOfBirth;

public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}
public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}
```

While saving the data to database my code is

```
ps.setDate(3, (Date) doctor.getDateOfBirth());
```

I have tried to solve it in many different ways but couldnt do it.

The error that is generated is

> Can't find a method to write property 'dateOfBirth' of type 'java.sql.Date' in a bean of type 'com.project.ocs.bean.DoctorBean'

If you got any other thing to know regarding my question, kindly convey that to me.